# Bootstrap inline form with labels above input

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to create an inline form using bootstrap with labels above input text fields but the result looks so messed up. 
This is what i tried:

```
<form id="form" method="post" class="form-inline" >
   <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-2">               
        <label for="from">from:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control form-text" />
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-2">
        <label for="to">to:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control form-text"/>
     </div>
     <div class="input-group date col-md-2" id="datepicker">
        <label for="checkin">check in</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control datepicker" name="processdate" />
        <span class="input-group-addon btn"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i> </span>
     </div>
     <div class="input-group date col-md-2" id="datepicker">
        <label for="checkout">check out</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control datepicker" name="processdate" />
        <span class="input-group-addon btn"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i> </span>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-2">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="submit"/>
     </div>
   </div>
 </form>
```

this is what i got:
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XrsKd.png) 
how do i get the submit button to right position and the glyphicons heights the same as the input fields what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made some edits to your html :  https://jsfiddle.net/05t4s041/

```
<form id="form" method="post" class="form-inline" >
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">               
      <label for="from">from:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control form-text" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <label for="to">to:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control form-text"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <label for="checkin">check in</label>
      <div class="input-group date" id="datepicker">
        <input type="text" class="form-control datepicker" name="processdate" />
        <span class="input-group-addon btn"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i> </span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <label for="checkout">check out</label>
      <div class="input-group date" id="datepicker">
        <input type="text" class="form-control datepicker" name="processdate" />
        <span class="input-group-addon btn"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i> </span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="submit"/>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: That works great thnks but the submit button is still not aligned with the rest of the fields

Answer (score 0):

you could put divs with bootstrap classes around your label and control like:

```
     <div class="col-md-2">     
        <div class="row">     
            <div class="col-md-6">          
                 <label for="from">from:</label>
            </div>
            <div class ="col-md-6">
                <input type="text" class="form-control form-text" />
            </div>
       </div>
    </div>
```

The row div may be sufficient:  it put's elements in a row put I like to put extra bootstrap classes around my controls so I can modify them. For example that the label has a smaller width than the control itself.

Comment: That doesn't work because i want labels above input fields and does not fix the glyphicon size

Comment: Oh whoops I'm sorry, I think I read the question wrong. Later today I'll fix it with the right answer